# pip3 install tensorflow problem with Input/output error

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying use tensorflow, but I always got this problem

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 823, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 682, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 262, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 780, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 833, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

I'm also trying reinstall tensorflow, but still got this problem

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/mimetypes.py", line 290, in guess_type
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/mimetypes.py", line 355, in init
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/mimetypes.py", line 205, in read
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/mimetypes.py", line 216, in readfp
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```